# I upgraded ubuntu to 12.10, and the internet does not work on vbox

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

Last week, I upgraded my operating system to Ubuntu 12.10 from 12.04, and the internet stopped working on two virtual machines (launched with virtualbox), Windows XP and OSX Snow Leopard.  OSX also stopped working completely at first, but I fixed that by switching to the 64 bit option in the vbox settings.  I switching to bridged networking from NAT restored the internet to Windows, but not to OSX.  Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Ubuntu 12.04 dns name resolve changed so that you should add "dns-nameservers" parameter to your /etc/network/interfaces file, like :

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Thanks!  Once I got the adapter back to "Intel PRO/1000 T Server (82543GC) and Vbox back to 4.1, this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

I had exectly same issue. You need to upgrade the VirtualBox to 4.2.X (that helped me)

Add one of the following lines according to your distribution to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian precise contrib
```

than:

```
wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.2
```

More about installation and post install steps you can read here:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: I tried this, but with 4.2 my Vbox lost the ability to load OSX.  This may be because my hardware is mac, but my host OS is ubuntu.  Thanks for trying, though.  On the plus side, while it was in 4.2, Windows seemed to run better.

Comment: I had this same problem, and this fixed it perfectly for me.

In fact, it also fixed another problem I was having with Windows 3.11 displaying stretched when I increased the resolution.

Answer (score 4):

As per thread here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2049230

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

solved the issue for me

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly for me on Xubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 3):

First check how is network configured in guests if its DHCP then probably they don't get DNS servers from host as after update Virualbox has no runing DNS service for nated guests thus they can't resolve hostnames.

There are two solutions 
1) Setup guest mashines to use 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 as DNS servers or recofigure Virtualbox to provide DNS proxy service

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnsproxy1 on
```

or

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnshostresolver1 on
```

Changing DNS server config in guests works for me the other solution might work (acording to VBox documentation) havent tested it myself

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Using 12.10 as a host and running Windows Vista as a guest. The following solved the problem:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm global --natdnshostresolver1 on
```

Source: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=50387

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with no network connection since upgrade to 12.10. I was getting the "DNS server is not responding" message.

`sudo apt-get install dnsmasq`

solved the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, none of the above solutions worked out in my case.

However, the following command, found [here](http://www.bewi.at/?p=713), made my day:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm "Your VM Name" --natdnshostresolver1 on
```

Hope that helps,